# LINQ: Can I load more than one generation of descendants with DataLoadOptions?

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, loadoptions

I'm using the following DataLoadOptions:

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Family>(f => f.FamilyLanguages);
options.LoadWith<FamilyLanguage>(fl => fl.Language);
```

The Family object comes back with a list of FamilyLanguages, but the FamilyLanguages have only got a LanguageID, the Language object is null.

This was working under Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2, but now I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 Release Candidate. Is this no longer the proper way to do this? Has there been some change to LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work.  Stackoverflow is not a good way to reach microsoft with beta bugs - try contacting microsoft directly.

Comment: Done: http://bit.ly/96dLua. Thanks for verifying this is a big, and that I wasn't doing something wrong.